# PowerShell: slice and dice tab delimited file

Tags: powershell, text, tabs, import-csv

I have a tab delimited text file produced by my backup software. I want to be able to import it as a PowerShell array using Import-CSV.

The problem is that the first 5 lines of the exported file prevent PowerShell from recognizing it as an array:

```
#List of Media
#Cell Manager: hpdp.domain.local
#Creation Date: 11/08/2018 9:36:09 AM
# Headers
# Medium ID Label   Location    Status  Protection  Used [MB]   Total [MB]  Last Used   Last Used_t Pool    Type
```

The way I am able to 'fix' this is by using notepad to delete the first four lines and remove the first # from the header line. The file then looks like this:

```
Medium ID   Label   Location    Status  Protection  Used [MB]   Total [MB]  Last Used   Last Used_t Pool    Type
id1:id2:id3:id5 [hostname] labelname_31 [Library:     5]    Good    13/08/2018 10:01:41 PM  762699.50   762699.50   14/07/2018 10:00:36 PM  1531828836  Tape Drive Pool LTO-Ultrium
```

I am trying to find a way to get PowerShell to make this change. For example, I try to remove the first four lines as a first step using this line:

```
(Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 4) | Set-Content $file
```

The file seems to then lose its tabs so it is no longer delimited.

How can I remove the lines as well as the first # without losing the tabs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your data doesn't have `#` in it then you can probably do `(Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 4) -replace ("#", "") | Set-Content $file`

Comment: Thanks I tried but it still loses the tabs. In fact, just doing "(Get-Content $file) | Set-Content $file" loses the tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by something like this

```
$data = Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 4 
$data[0] = $data[0] -replace '^#\s*', ''
```

now you can overwrite the file if you want to:

```
$data | Set-Content $file -Force
```

or use it directly as object in Powershell (a csv object is an array of PSObjects)

```
$csv = ($data -join [environment]::NewLine) | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"
```

or use this converted object to write out the file again

```
$csv | Export-Csv -Path $file -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestions but they all produce a malformed file with no tabs

Comment: hum... they all worked on my machine. Are you absolutely sure the input file is Tab delimited and not more like a Fixed-Width file? You are showing us just one line of data so I can't tell.

Comment: How do you check the outputted file for tabs? Notepad or a more advanced reader like EditPlus where you can have it show these 'hidden' characters. Try reading it in in Excel with **Data -> From Text File -> Delimited -> Tab**

Comment: When I open it in Notepad++ and search for \t (Extended) it highlights all the spaces between the "cells". So that is proof the file is tab delimited. Again, if I manually edit this file in Notepad to remove the unwanted chars and save the tabs are retained. I am just trying to figure out how to do this in PowerShell. Thanks.

Comment: Is that also true for the headers? What does `($data -join [environment]::NewLine) | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"` display?

Comment: As per the Notepad++ Wiki: _The View -> View Symbol -> Show White Space and TAB toggle menu item turns display of whitespace on and off. Tabs show as arrows pointing right. Spaces show as small dots._

Comment: I can confirm Notepad++ shows the spaces between cells and headers as arrows. They start at Line 5 (# Medium ID...).

When I run your lines I get what I would expect when running ("$importedCSV") | FL

Comment: I think i'm losing you now.. Once the 4 toplines are removed and the `#` is gone from the header line, The line `$csv = ($data -join [environment]::NewLine) | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "\`t"` should give you a valid CSV in Powershell format. This **IS** what you wanted in the first place, no? That object `$csv` can then be written to disk with any delimiter you want. Try exporting it to a NEW file (don't overwrite the original) and load that in your Notepad++

Comment: Sorry it’s late here and I just thought about your last point. But you’re right - I tried saving to the same file, I’ll try to save to new and will let you know. Thanks again

Comment: OK I can confirm this is working!!! Thank you so much Theo, really appreciate your help! As you said there was really no need to export any file, all I needed was to have the filtered data in a variable! Now I can use this file as a proper table in my script! Woohoo!!

Comment: Glad to have been able to help